# How can I stream a map of objects and map flatten to a single list of a new object?

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to figure out the best way to handle the following scenario.

I have a map of events that happened in the database grouped by timestamp:

```
[2016-04-01 00:00:00, [event1, event2, event 3]]
[2016-02-01 00:00:00, [event5, event6]]
[2016-01-01 00:00:00, [event7, event8, event9, event10]]
```

I would like to present this data in a tableview with a single row per event timestamp.  However some values with in the event might repeat.

For example:

Event definition is

```
class Event () {    
    LocalDateTime timestamp
    String eventName
    String eventDescription
}
```

I was thinking to flatten to a structure like this

```
class DisplayEvent () {    
    LocalDateTime timestamp
    Collection<String> eventName
    Collection<String> eventDescription
}
```

So that after converting the original map I am left with the following list:

```
displayEvent1
displayEvent2
displayEvent3
```

Where each display event has the key from the original event but an array of all the variable data.

I created the map as follows:

```
Map<LocalDateTime, List<Event>> eventsByTimestamp =
                    events
                    .stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ev -> ev.timestampProperty().get()));
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Maybe reduce is a better word than flatten, some ideas pop up then :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my eyes the best approach depends on the details of your task.

A more generic approach would be a class `Event`:

```
public class Event
{
    LocalDateTime timestamp;
    String eventName;
    String eventDescription;
}
```

Then you may elegantly create groupings by the timestamp:

```
event.
    stream().
    collect(groupingBy(Event::getTimeStamp));
```

This of course is not so efficient and will work nice for fewer events. So you may consider grouping the events during their extraction from the database, for example:

```
public class EventRepository
{
    Map<LocalDateTime, List<Event>> getAllEventsGroupedByTime(); 
}
```

In `getAllEventsGroupedByTime` you will instantiate the event objects and put them in the corresponding group without repeating this calculations in another application layer.

The alternative approach is something like this:

```
public class Event
{
    String eventName;
    String eventDescription;
}

public class EventGroup
{
     LocalDateTime timestamp;
     List<Event> events;
}

public class EventGroupRepository
{
    List<EventGroups> getEventGroups(); 
}
```

Honestly I see little benefits in the second solution (e.g. some object refs are spared). So I would go for no.1 and group them during the extraction from the DB especially if the number of events is not so huge. This seems somehow more sexy, because the event time naturally belongs to the event.

**Update:**

Ok it seems that you would like to convert all your events to a collection of display events using cool java 8 streams :-) You may then consider adding the following simple methods to `DisplayEvent` (or create some kind of helper class):

```
public static DisplayEvent combine(DisplayEvent evt1, DisplayEvent evt2)
{
    if (evt1.getActivityTimestamp() == null)
        evt1.setActivityTimestamp(evt2.getActivityTimestamp());

    //TODO: transfer all names from evt2 to evt 1
    // check if timestamps match, optimize, etc

    return evt1;
}

public static DisplayEvent fromEvent(Event evt)
{
    DisplayEvent dispEvt = new DisplayEvent();

    //todo copy the necessary stuff to dispEvt

    return dispEvt;
}
```

Then the lambda may look like this:

```
Collection<DisplayEvent> displayEvents = 
              events.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        ev -> ev.activityTimestampProperty(),
                        Collectors.reducing(
                                        new DisplayEvent(), 
                                        DisplayEvent::fromEvent, 
                                        DisplayEvent::combine))).values();
```

*Disclaimer: I do not like this very much :-) so personally I would stick to a non `DisplayEvent` solution.*

Comment: Your solution provides me with what I started with unfortunately.  Thanks for the input, but I was looking to flatten into a single list with the repeated data within it.  I used a foreach and transformed that way - which solves my issues.

Comment: Ok, maybe it is my fault because I should have included DisplayEvent in my proposed solution. I gave it another try. See the update

Comment: Didn't think to use reduce. Will give it a shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution which works, but isn't fully a lambda expression which I had hoped for.

```
events
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ev -> ev.activityTimestampProperty().get()))
    .forEach((key,v) -> {
        DisplayEvent de = new DisplayEvent();
        de.activityTimestamp.set(key);
        for (Event event : v) {
            de.userName.set(event.getUserName());
            de.eventDescriptions.add(event.getEventDescription());
            de.eventNames.add(event.geEventName());
        }
        displayActivities.add(dha);
    });
```